# A little bit wondering of memory management on ios

Tags: ios, memory-management, retain

I have many viewControllers.

and all of them have many retained properties.

so, I would add these code to every viewControllers:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.every_retained_property = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [every_retained_property release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Till now things all go well in my app.

But I heard that,

```
a_retained_property = newValue;
// equals to
[a_retained_property release];
a_retained_property = [newValue retain];
```

so if I've already set a_retained_property to nil in viewDidUnload,

it is neccessary to release a_retained_property in dealloc, like what I am doing?

I just wonder it.

Thanks!

Comment: Search in Stackoverflow or google for viewDidUnload vs dealloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not do you any harm, put it that way. But

```
a_retained_property = newValue;
```

is not equivalent to:

```
[a_retained_property release];
a_retained_property = [newValue retain];
```

Instead you should use:

```
self.a_retained_property = newValue;
```

Comment: I will argue that `self.a_retained_property = nil` is preferable to `[a_retained_property release]`, because the former also rids your variable of a reference to an object that perhaps no longer exists. It's a little cleaner and might save you headaches as your code grows in complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you need to release your instance variables in the dealloc method is that the viewDidUnload method is typically only called after your view has been removed from memory because of a low memory condition. Under normal conditions the method will never be called, so if you don't release your instance variables in dealloc, when you release your view controller you will get a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

What Philip said. Also I will add that I try to 'purify' my view lifecycle callbacks to maintaining UIKit artifacts only, and maintain my model and controller objects elsewhere.